# SharePoint 2010 lookup column not displaying

Tags: sharepoint-2010, lookup

I have encountered a strange bug with a listview webpart. On a 'city' lookup column, the data will not display when I have a 'Full Toolbar'. It will display when I change it to 'Summary Toolbar' or 'None'.

The strange part is, I can filter / sort the lookup column by the existing values but the column itself is blank. Also, when I go into the list itself, the lookup data is displaying fine.

Has anybody come across this bug? It works fine in SharePoint 2007.

Comment: This might be a branding issue, SP2010 is not totally fail-proof of those, have you tried different browsers?

Comment: I tried IE 7 - IE 10 same result :/